# Saving the selected row for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to save the selected row for my UITableView. So, when the user comes back to the screen, it shows their last selection.

This is the code I tried, which, i thought would do the trick:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    self.lastIndexPathUsed = indexPath;
    NSData *responseData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:indexPath];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:responseData forKey:@"IndexPathData"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Then in my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSData *responseData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"IndexPathData"];

    NSIndexPath *index = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:responseData];
    self.lastIndexPath = index;


}
```

However, `responseData` hasn't have the index path saved. Its always NULL. Even in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: take an mutablearray in app delegate and add object the index of index path.row in didiselectrow .. when you come back just show them

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking?

Comment: I really don't want to use appDelegate to store or hold any values. Thanks for the idea I will try use a mutable array.

Comment: @remus5 the code I posted doesn't work. Trying to find a solution that will work. To save the last selected indexpath.row

Comment: `self.lastIndexPathUsed != self.lastIndexPath` ?!?

Comment: Do not save NSData in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it as two values and recreate the NSIndexPath later:

Save indexPath.row and indexPath.section separately then recreate it with:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]
```

Comment: Indexpath.colum doesn't exist?

Comment: This actually was a better solution once I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUserDefaults *userdefaults                        = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userdefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] forKey:@"lastIndexPathUsed"];

}
```

Then in viewDidLoad Method

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.lastIndexPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastIndexPathUsed"];
}
```